# Why is it true that $F_{q^n} = F_q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the primitive element of $F_{q^n}$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Since $\alpha$ is the primitive element of $F_{q^n}$ then $F_{q^n} = \{0, \alpha, \alpha^2,\cdots, \alpha^{q^{n -2}} , 1\}$. Then how $F_q(\alpha)$ is equivalent to $F_{q^n}$? Because what I understand $F_q(\alpha)$ is extension of $F_q$ by adjoining $\alpha$ alone.

Comment: Supposed that you know that $\alpha$ has degree $n$ over $F_q$, we have that $F_q(\alpha)$ is an $n$ dimensional vector field over $F_q$, hence it has $q^n$ elements. Now, finite fields are unique for each possible cardinality (i.e. prime powers).

Comment: When you adjoin an element to a field to get an extension field, you must also include all those elements that are necessary to insure that the end result is also a field. So $K(\alpha)$ will automatically contain elements such as $1+\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, because a field is closed under addition and multiplication. By induction you will then see that all the powers of $\alpha$ must be included. Thus you get all of $F_{q^n}$. OTOH that is already a field, so you are done.